# droppable draggable is overlapping divs when moved

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable, resizable

When i move the divs into the drop zone and then move then on top of each other, the bottom one becomes the top one, and then when i move the top one it does the same thing.

How can i stop this from happening, so if i want the blue on on the bottom and the red div on top of it, at the moment the red jump would jump below the blue one. But i cant get this to stop doing this

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mvpkzzdt/

here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });

    $('#main').droppable({

        drop: function (e, ui) {

            x = ui.helper.clone();

            //x.removeClass("display").addClass("area");
            x.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
            x.draggable({
                containment: '#main',
            }).resizable({
                containment: "#main"
            });

            x.css({ top:ui.offset.top, left: ui.offset.left});

            x.appendTo('#main');
            ui.helper.remove();

            //editDataTypes();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after alot of attempts lol

here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mvpkzzdt/1/

```
$("#main").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(event, ui){
        var ud = ui.draggable;
        if( ud.draggable( "option", "helper" ) == "clone" ){
            ud.clone().removeClass("display").addClass("area")
            .appendTo("#main")
                .css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: ui.offset.left,
                    top: ui.offset.top
                })
                .resizable()
                .draggable({cursor: "move", containment: '#main'})
                //editDataTypes();
        }else{
        ud.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: ui.offset.left,
                top: ui.offset.top
            })
        }
    },
    out: function(event, ui){
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: @sri Why can't you see any difference?

Comment: @rageit May be I didn't look into it properly. I accept my mistake and am deleting my comment.